# Meet OOM when I want to fetch more than 1,000,000 rows in apache-spark

Tags: apache-spark

**Problem:**
I want to query my table which stored in Hive through the SparkSQL JDBC interface.
And want to fetch more than 1,000,000 rows. But met OOM.
sql = `"select * from TEMP_ADMIN_150601_000001 limit XXX ";`

**My Env:**
5 Nodes = One master + 4 workers,  1000M Network Switch ,  Redhat 6.5
Each node: 8G RAM, 500G Harddisk
Java 1.6, Scala 2.10.4, Hadoop 2.6, Spark 1.3.0, Hive 0.13

**Data:**
A table with user and there charge for electricity data.
About 1,600,000 Rows. About 28MB.
Each row occupy about 18 Bytes. 
2 columns: `user_id String, total_num Double`

**Repro Steps:**
 1. Start Spark
 2. Start SparkSQL thriftserver, command:

```
/usr/local/spark/spark-1.3.0/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh \
--master spark://cx-spark-001:7077 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=4g \
--conf spark.driver.memory=2g \
--conf spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.manager=sort \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" \
--conf spark.file.transferTo=false \
--conf spark.akka.timeout=2000 \
--conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.4 \
--conf spark.cores.max=8 \
--conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb=256 \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
--conf spark.akka.frameSize=512 \
--driver-class-path /usr/local/hive/lib/classes12.jar
```

4. Run the test code, see it in attached file: testHiveJDBC.java
5. Get the OOM:GC overhead limit exceeded  or OOM: java heap space   or  lost worker heartbeat after 120s.  see the attached logs.

**Preliminary diagnose:**
 6. When fetching less than 1,000,000 rows , it always success.
 7. When fetching more than 1,300,000 rows , it always fail with OOM: GC overhead limit exceeded.
 8. When fetching about 1,040,000-1,200,000 rows, if query right after the thrift server start up, most times success. if I successfully query once then retry the same query, it will fail.
 9. There are 3 dead pattern: OOM:GC overhead limit exceeded  or OOM: java heap space   or  lost worker heartbeat after 120s.
 10. I tried to start thrift with different configure, give the worker 4G MEM or 2G MEM , got the same behavior. That means , no matter the total MEM of worker, i can get less than 1,000,000 rows, and can not get more than 1,300,000 rows.

**Preliminary conclusions:**
 11. The total data is less than 30MB, It is so small, And there is no complex computation operation. 
So the failure is not caused by excessive memory requirements.
So I guess there are some defect in spark sql code.
 12. Allocate 2G or 4G MEM to each worker, got same behavior.
This point strengthen my doubts: there are some defect in code. But I can't find the specific location.

Comment: I'd look at the database query log for clues, query optimizer might be behaving in an unexpected way.
I've had issues with JDBC as well and found out each worker was executing a very large number of queries instead of just one per partition as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Because spark workers send all task results to driver program (ThriftServer) and the driver program will [collect all task results](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/34e71c6d89c1f2b6236dbf0d75cd12da08003c84/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1833) into `org.apache.spark.sql.Row[TASK_COUNT][ROW_COUNT]` array.

This is the root cause to make ThriftServer OOM.

Answer (score 0):

What you additionally could try is to set `spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollects` to `true`. The effects are described in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25224 pretty nicely!